# Spring: Returning empty HTTP Responses with ResponseEntity<Void> doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

We are implementing a REST API with Spring (4.1.1.). For certain HTTP requests, we would like to return a head with no body as a response. However, using `ResponseEntity<Void>` doesn't seem to work. When called with a `MockMvc` test, a 406 (Not acceptable) is returned. Using `ResponseEntity<String>` without a parameter value (`new  ResponseEntity<String>( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND )`) works fine.

Method:

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.HEAD, value = Constants.KEY )
public ResponseEntity<Void> taxonomyPackageExists( @PathVariable final String key ) {

    LOG.debug( "taxonomyPackageExists queried with key: {0}", key ); //$NON-NLS-1$

    final TaxonomyKey taxonomyKey = TaxonomyKey.fromString( key );

    LOG.debug( "Taxonomy key created: {0}", taxonomyKey ); //$NON-NLS-1$

    if ( this.xbrlInstanceValidator.taxonomyPackageExists( taxonomyKey ) ) {

        LOG.debug( "Taxonomy package with key: {0} exists.", taxonomyKey ); //$NON-NLS-1$

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>( HttpStatus.OK );

    } else {

        LOG.debug( "Taxonomy package with key: {0} does NOT exist.", taxonomyKey ); //$NON-NLS-1$

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND );
    }

}
```

Test case (TestNG):

```
public class TaxonomyQueryControllerTest {

private XbrlInstanceValidator   xbrlInstanceValidatorMock;
private TaxonomyQueryController underTest;
private MockMvc                 mockMvc;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    this.xbrlInstanceValidatorMock = createMock( XbrlInstanceValidator.class );
    this.underTest = new TaxonomyQueryController( this.xbrlInstanceValidatorMock );
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup( this.underTest ).build();
}

@Test
public void taxonomyPackageDoesNotExist() throws Exception {
    // record
    expect( this.xbrlInstanceValidatorMock.taxonomyPackageExists( anyObject( TaxonomyKey.class ) ) ).andStubReturn(
            false );

    // replay
    replay( this.xbrlInstanceValidatorMock );

    // do the test
    final String taxonomyKey = RestDataFixture.taxonomyKeyString;

    this.mockMvc.perform( head( "/taxonomypackages/{key}", taxonomyKey ).accept( //$NON-NLS-1$
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML ) ).andExpect( status().isNotFound() );

}

}
```

Fails with this stack trace:

```
FAILED: taxonomyPackageDoesNotExist
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<404> but was:<406>
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:652)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:153)
at de.zeb.control.application.xbrlstandalonevalidator.restservice.TaxonomyQueryControllerTest.taxonomyPackageDoesNotExist(TaxonomyQueryControllerTest.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: Actually ResponseEntity<Void> works perfectly. See examples here: http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-responseentity-bodybuilder-responseentity-enhancements-example

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**NOTE: This is true for the version mentioned in the question, 4.1.1.RELEASE.**

Spring MVC handles a `ResponseEntity` return value through `HttpEntityMethodProcessor`.

When the `ResponseEntity` value doesn't have a body set, as is the case in your snippet, `HttpEntityMethodProcessor` tries to determine a content type for the response body from the parameterization of the `ResponseEntity` return type in the signature of the `@RequestMapping` handler method.

So for

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> taxonomyPackageExists( @PathVariable final String key ) {
```

that type will be `Void`. `HttpEntityMethodProcessor` will then loop through all its registered `HttpMessageConverter` instances and find one that can write a body for a `Void` type. Depending on your configuration, it may or may not find any.

If it does find any, it still needs to make sure that the corresponding body will be written with a Content-Type that matches the type(s) provided in the request's `Accept` header, `application/xml` in your case.

If after all these checks, no such `HttpMessageConverter` exists, Spring MVC  will decide that it cannot produce an acceptable response and therefore return a 406 Not Acceptable HTTP response.

With `ResponseEntity<String>`, Spring will use `String` as the response body and find `StringHttpMessageConverter` as a handler. And since `StringHttpMessageHandler` can produce content for any media type (provided in the `Accept` header), it will be able to handle the `application/xml` that your client is requesting.

**Spring MVC has since been changed to only return 406 if the body in the `ResponseEntity` is NOT `null`. You won't see the behavior in the original question if you're using a more recent version of Spring MVC.**

---

In [iddy85's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550756/438154), which seems to suggest `ResponseEntity<?>`, the type for the body will be inferred as `Object`. If you have the correct libraries in your classpath, ie. Jackson (version > 2.5.0) and its XML extension, Spring MVC will have access to `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` which it can use to produce `application/xml` for the type `Object`. **Their solution only works under these conditions.** Otherwise, it will fail for the same reason I've described above.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, thanks for your reply. Just be sure: You are in effect saying that I have to use ResponseEntity <String>, right?

Comment: @MatthiasT One option is to set the return type to `ResponseEntity<?>` and use whatever when constructing the actual return value. You can also provide `HttpHeaders` with an appropriate content-type to the `ResponseEntity` constructor. Though it does not really make sense to set a content-type when you have no content.

Comment: If you use ResponseEntity<?> and then set a responseEntity with no body, isn't the body still void? meaning you have the same issue?

Comment: From my tests, setting ResponseEntity<Void> will write a "null" on responseBody which is pretty buggy. If you really intend to have an empty responseBody, return a ResponseEntity<String> with an empty String like "return ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK)"

Comment: @Renatinn That depends on what `HttpMessageConverter` instances you have registered. But, sure, an empty string also works.

Answer (score 60):

According [Spring 4 MVC ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder and ResponseEntity Enhancements Example](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-responseentity-bodybuilder-responseentity-enhancements-example) it could be written as:

```
....
   return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
....
   return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
```

UPDATE:

If returned value is `Optional`, there are convenient method, returned `ok()` or `notFound()`:

```java
return ResponseEntity.of(optional)
```

UPDATE 2: also feel free to use for status `OK(200)`

```
public void taxonomyPackageExists(...
```

and for status `NO_CONTENT(204)`

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void taxonomyPackageExists(...
```

Answer (score 16):

You can also not specify the type parameter which seems a bit cleaner and what Spring intended when looking at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ResponseEntity(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus)):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.HEAD, value = Constants.KEY )
public ResponseEntity taxonomyPackageExists( @PathVariable final String key ){
    // ...
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

For Spring 5.2+ this works for me:

```
@PostMapping("/foo")
ResponseEntity<Void> foo(@PathVariable UUID fooId) {
    return fooService.findExam(fooId)
            .map(uri -> ResponseEntity.noContent().<Void>build())
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Your method implementation is ambiguous, try the following , edited your code  a little bit and used `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` i.e 204 No Content as in place of `HttpStatus.OK`

> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.

*Any value of **T** will be ignored for 204,  but not for 404*

```
  public ResponseEntity<?> taxonomyPackageExists( @PathVariable final String key ) {
            LOG.debug( "taxonomyPackageExists queried with key: {0}", key ); //$NON-NLS-1$
            final TaxonomyKey taxonomyKey = TaxonomyKey.fromString( key );
            LOG.debug( "Taxonomy key created: {0}", taxonomyKey ); //$NON-NLS-1$

            if ( this.xbrlInstanceValidator.taxonomyPackageExists( taxonomyKey ) ) {
                LOG.debug( "Taxonomy package with key: {0} exists.", taxonomyKey ); //$NON-NLS-1$
                 return new ResponseEntity<T>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            } else {
               LOG.debug( "Taxonomy package with key: {0} does NOT exist.", taxonomyKey ); //$NON-NLS-1$
                return new ResponseEntity<T>( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND );
            }

    }
```

Comment: T is a response body type, could be anything, String is an option.try that if it does`t work share the new code with and the stack-trace. @SotiriosDelimanolis I am curious what`s wrong with the code?

Comment: Is `T` a type variable? Where is it declared? What differences will your suggestions make.

Comment: I did not change anything  dramatic from the the original code rather than suggesting the use of HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT instead of HttpStatus.OK for a no body response

Comment: So please explain how that will fix the OP's problem.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, to deal with empty responses, I use in my Integration Tests the MockMvcResponse object like this :

```
MockMvcResponse response = RestAssuredMockMvc.given()
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .when()
                .get("/v1/ticket");

    assertThat(response.mockHttpServletResponse().getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value());
```

and in my controller I return empty response in a specific case like this :

```
return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
```