# Camel REST service throws Exception when returning null

Tags: java, rest, exception, apache-camel, http-status-code-404

I have a simple REST service. There are clients and I can get a client by its ID. In case there is no client with the requested ID, a 404 not found should be returned.

Here's the relevant part:

```
rest("/client")
    .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
    .get("{id}")
        .to("direct:getClient");

from("direct:getClient")
    .bean(clientService, "getClient(${header.id})")
     .choice()
        .when(simple("${body} == null"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(404));
```

Everything is fine when clients can be found, however, when the client is not found and clientService returns null, I get the following stack trace:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpMessage.createBody(HttpMessage.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:47)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$StreamCachingAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:799)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$StreamCachingAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:767)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:246)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:573)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
```

I can't figure this one out. Returning null from a bean method call should be possible, right?

Comment: What Camel version do you use? And what Camel component do you use with rest-dsl as HTTP ?

Comment: 2.18.0 and camel-servlet

Comment: Ok... there seems to be a bug in 2.18.0. I downgraded to 2.17.3 and it works fine. This is a serious issue, I'll create a test and report it.

Comment: I found the bug and logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10425

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was planning to do that today :)

Answer (score 0):

Try as a workaround to use

```
.setBody().method(clientService, "getClient(${header.id})")
```

I suspect its the .bean() that has a little bug when you return a `null` value as the new message body, which fools the underlying `HttpMessage` into thinking the message body hasn't been initialized yet, and thus you get that stream error reading the stream again.

Comment: That does makes sense. However, it also doesn't work, but the error is slightly different: "org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: getClient(${header.id}) on null due to: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed". This message seems to say that clientService is null (the 'on null'), but that is definitely not the case, as everything works fine when getClient returns a non-null result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that main idea that you can throw new exception SomeClassException if the clientid not found in your bean and handle in rest route

```
public class SomeClassException  extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2542653496302641967L;    
    public SomeClassException() {
    }    
    public SomeClassException(String arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }
}
```

your route:

```
                rest("/client/")
                .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .get("{id}")
                    .to("direct:getClient");

                onException(SomeClassException.class) .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(404)).handled(true);

                from("direct:getClient")
                .bean(clientService, "getClient(${header.id})")
                ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue when returning `NO_CONTENT` on the route on a method that had the option to return an object or not depending on if anything was queued. The code was structured like so:

```java
rest("/foo")
    .get("/bar").route().to("direct:foo").endRest()
;

from("direct:bar")
    .process(exchange -> {
        // ... service calls that eventually resulted in this ...
        //       (status code of 204 and a body of null)
        ResponseEntity responseEntity = 
exchange.getIn().getBody(ResponseEntity.class);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
        exchange.getIn().setBody(responseEntity.getBody());
    })
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
;
```

I was experiencing the same error, `org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed`, even though I was stepping through my code and seeing everything process as expected. Like you, everything worked fine when the method returned an object, but only threw this exception when the body was set to `null`.

At this point, I figured there was some complicated series of events in Camel that goes wrong when the response body is set to `null`. Stepping through the code wasn't as helpful as I would have hoped, so I just looked up what the standard practice for a response entity was in the case of `NO_CONTENT` or `NOT_FOUND` and stumbled across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550124/spring-returning-empty-http-responses-with-responseentityvoid-doesnt-work). I believe Camel works in the same way with converters and requires some type of object, so I just modified my code like so:

```java
exchange.getIn().setBody(responseEntity.getBody() == null ? "" : responseEntity.getBody());
```

As a result, there is still no body in the message returned to clients, and there is no more `IOException: Stream closed` error.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a specific scenario when the similar error is thrown where the root cause is the invalid Json.

Considering this specific example:

```
 String tempDate = yourExchangeObject.getIn().getBody(String.class);
 JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject(tempDate); //Exception
```