# What is the best way to return an empty ResponseEntity with Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

what would be the best return type for my controller if I return an empty `ResponseEntity`?

For example if I want to return a 204 - no content using  `ResponseEntity.noContent().build()` should the return of my fonction  be `ResponseEntity<?>`, `ResponseEntity<Void>` or just `ResponseEntity`

Comment: Put ResponseEntity<Void> because you don't return a body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring: Returning empty HTTP Responses with ResponseEntity<Void> doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550124/spring-returning-empty-http-responses-with-responseentityvoid-doesnt-work)

Comment: it doesn't really tell me which of these 3 propositions is the best

Comment: _"it doesn't really tell me which of these 3 propositions is the best"_ -- because "best" is a matter of opinion.  Just aim for something that is easy for you to read and understand, since it'll make future maintenance easier.

Comment: Your rest controller method should return ResponseEntity<Void>. Then, you can add any headers and  status you want. For example: HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();  headers.add(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, baseUri + "/api/contacts/" + id);   and finally: return new ResponseEntity<>(null, headers, HttpStatus.FOUND)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ResponseEntity<Void> with HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT
```

Comment: is it really the best solution? if so why?

Comment: There is no best solution in this case, both ResponseEntity<Void> and ResponseEntity work. I would use ResponseEntity<Void> because it indicates what is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

i would prefer `ResponseEntity.noContent().build()` which clearly say's what it doing, Return type can be just `ResponseEntity`

I personally like return type without 'Void' looks clean to me.

spring docs says below

```
public ResponseEntity(HttpStatus statusCode)
```

> Create a new ResponseEntity with the given status code, and no body
>   nor headers.
>
> *Parameters:*
>   **statusCode** - *the status code*

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ResponseEntity(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus)

Comment: but what should I put as the return type?

Comment: thanks, but is it really the best solution?