# Spring : ResponseEntity<String> return empty value

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm working with a small module with Spring (5.0.8) and i'm looking to make some logs for debugging purposes. 
My ResponseEntity return an empty value and after some research, I can't figure out why.
I've been going through some post like this one [Spring: Returning empty HTTP Responses with ResponseEntity<Void> doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550124/spring-returning-empty-http-responses-with-responseentityvoid-doesnt-work) but i haven't found a suitable solution for my case.

```
private RestTemplate buildRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = buildBasicRestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(
            REST_ADMIN_USERNAME,
            REST_ADMIN_PASSWORD));
    return restTemplate;
}
```

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = buildRestTemplate();        
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<ActivityLogBean> entity = new HttpEntity<ActivityLogBean>(headers);
String resourceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/rest/data/timestamp"
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uriWithParams, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Could you please show your code.

Comment: For privacy reasons, i can't post all my code. All i know is its actually working.

Comment: 1) you can make a minimal POC without exposing your privacy data - doing so will probably show you what the error is. 2) is you response containing a value, which is not returned correctly from the controller? Have you specified what is the ResponseBody of your controller method? Are you using @RestController annotation?