# Spring boot @Transactional does not work when org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException is thrown?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a rest controller, it will insert 1 record per request,like:

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@PostMapping("/create_user")
public Response<Empty> createUser(@RequestBody Request<CreateUserRequest> body) {
    String openId = body.getData().getOpenId();
    String phoneNumber = body.getData().getPhoneNumber();
    weChatMapper.createWechatUser(WechatUser.builder()
            .openId(openId)
            .phoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .build());
    return Response.of();
}
```

Then when i call it , throws `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException`, seems that somthing goes wrong when serializing the response.Then i check database, i find that 1 record has been inserted, not rolling back.
Then i add a exception throwing code before returning, like:

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@PostMapping("/create_user")
public Response<Empty> createUser(@RequestBody Request<CreateUserRequest> body) {
    String openId = body.getData().getOpenId();
    String phoneNumber = body.getData().getPhoneNumber();
    weChatMapper.createWechatUser(WechatUser.builder()
            .openId(openId)
            .phoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .build());
    if (true) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("my test exception");
    }
    return Response.of();
 }
```

Call again, the record is not inserted, roll back as expected.But why...? It's very strange.How to make it roll back at this kind of situation?

The complete trace:

```
2023-02-27 18:42:36.100 ERROR 36244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.digiwin.vssmp_backend.entity.Empty]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.digiwin.vssmp_backend.entity.Empty and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.digiwin.vssmp_backend.dto.response.Response["data"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.digiwin.vssmp_backend.entity.Empty and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.digiwin.vssmp_backend.dto.response.Response["data"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:46) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1518) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:456) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:183) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_332]
```

Comment: life hack - dont start your transactions in controllers but rather in services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpMessageConversionException` happens outside of your controller method (inside spring MVC guts but after handler method) as whatever your method returns, cannot be serialized to a requested form. Therfore, transaction is started, commited and then exception is thrown.

When you throw exception "manually" it is done from withing the method causing TX to be rolled back as expected.

Comment: In view of the situation where this exception occurs externally, how to use the @Transactional annotation to make the transaction roll back normally?

Comment: It sholdnt as processing is done. Eg in gambling, would your like your bet to NOT be accepted only because you had poor internet connection? Anyhow, you always will have a layer above currently tarnsaction handling layer that might fail and you will not be able to rollback it then. **As for how?** I dont know and actually I dont really care to find out as it is a bad practice imo.

Comment: Its like doing buying and estate and sending the confirmation via traditional mail. You dont expect the transaction to be invalidated only because mailman got sick and didnt deliver the confirmation to the recipient right? Nor you shoud here.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction is not rolled back because *createUser()* is executed successfully and the exception is thrown later when Jackson tries to serialize your Response to json. You can double-check this by creating a unit-test and directly call the *createUser* method from the controller, without the web layer.

The exception is thrown because your Response does not expose any data (or it does not contain any). For instance, if you run this simple unit test you will get the same exception:

```
@Test
void test() throws Exception {
    var bean = new MyObject(123);
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // will throw the same exception
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(bean)); 
}

class MyObject {
    private int value;

    public MyObject(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Though, if you add a getter to the MyObject class and re-run the test, this time it will pass.

Comment: In view of the situation where this exception occurs externally, how to use the @Transactional annotation to make the transaction roll back normally?

Comment: If you want to roll back if the json serialization fails you can, for example, make the controller return String and manually create the json like this: `return mapper.writeValueAsString(response)`.

Though, I believe this might not be the best design because they represent different layers of abstraction. There should be better ways of fixing this: you can start by looking at this class `com.digiwin.vssmp_backend.dto.response.Response` or check how to return an empty body: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550124/spring-returning-empty-http-responses-with-responseentityvoid-doesnt-work

Comment: Then servlet layer can fail due to a multilude of reasons as OP still wants to TX to be rolled back because of reasons...